# Filtering with Where statement doesnt work

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable<DataRow> myObjects` which I would like to filter with a Where statement as follows:

```
myObjects = myObjects.Where(o => o["someVar"] != true)
```

...but I cant get it to work. In my case myObjects contains 1 object, for which I am positive that o["someVar"] == true. But after filtering, `myObjects` still contains that 1 object.

Now if I use another filtering mechanism , like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in myObjects)
{
    if (row["someVar"] == true) {continue;}
    else {filtered.Add(row)}
}
```

...then filtered correctly contains 0 rows.

I have tried casting ToList() before as well as after the Where clause. Both didnt work.

I have also tried not re-assigning to the same variable, like `myObjects2 = myObjects.Where(o => o["someVar"] != true)`. That also did not matter.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit** I am sorry about starting confusion by not being clear about this pseudo code. In fact, the `IEnumerable<T>` was of type `IEnumerable<SomeCustomInterface>` which can be safely casted to DataRow. Also, the logical statement `o["someVar"] == true` was in reality a bit different, and not really a DataRow operation. The comments about this statement not working in case of a DataRow are absolutely true.

**Fixed**. By starting out with `ICollection<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`. Then made a `List<T> filtered = myObjects.Where(o => somelogicalstatement).ToList()`. Filtered now contains 0 objects.

Comment: What type is `o`? Your `myObjects` is an `IEnumerable<T>`,  but what is T? I can assure you that Linq's `.Where` method has been battled test millions (billions?) of times, and it does work properly. The problem lays with your code, but you've got to show us enough of it that we can help you find exactly what it is.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle demonstrating the .Where does indeed work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cOUWgc) with your code, when the type of the object being filtered is set up properly. My guess is that `o["someVar"]` does not contain the value you think it contains, despite your assertions to the contrary. We need a [mcve] to be sure.

Comment: It is an IEnumerable<DataRow>. Sorry the <> part was left out by the markup language

Comment: How are you verifying that `Where` doesn't work? I suspect you are looking in the debugger, which is tricky for verifying Linq queries. If you do `myObjects.ToList()` in the debugger do you still see the rows that should be filtered?

Comment: Did you get a compiler error you [failed to tell us about](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kU8RiB)? The indexer for a DataRow returns an object, not a boolean. You said that it failed to filter and that the resulting collection returned a different amount that you expected. You didn't mention a compiler error. So again, I ask you to provide a [mcve] so we can tell what's really going on, and to accurately describe the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: try `true.Equals(o["someVar"])`

Comment: @DStanley I agree, or `Object.Equals(o["someVar"], true)`

Comment: Or better yet, don't use a DataTable/DataRow if you can help it. There are some situations where a DataTable is useful (such as using [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy)). But generally, working with an custom type that correctly models  your data is going to be easier and more efficient.

Comment: FIxed. By starting out with ICollection<T> instead of IEnumerable<T>. Then made a List<T> filtered = myObjects.Where(o => somelogicalstatement).ToList(). Filtered now contains 0 objects. 

You are right about the pseudo code not being entirely clear. Sorry for that. I'm still learning to ask good questions. I was struggling how to give sufficiently detailed info without having to refer to a lot of custom datatypes, about which I then would need to elaborate. Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: Using an ICollection instead of IEnumerable would not fix the compilation issue that you've shown here. I've asked several questions for clarification here that you need to answer. Even if you're new to coding, the directions on the [mcve] documentation explain several techniques for narrowing the problem down while still providing enough information that you have a complete example.

Comment: @jnz changing `IEnumerable` to `ICollection` would do nothing to fix this issue. The `Where` method would act on the `IEnumerable` anyway, regardless of what type you declare outside of it.